# How to get a geo google chart of a specific country only

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to get a map of South Africa, but it should only display South Africa and not the other countries and ocean surrounding it in Google Charts.

Is it possible? I've scoured the net in trying to find a solution to this but failing.

This the code of the google chart needed to display South Africa:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['geochart'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

    function drawMarkersMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Province', 'Successful Deliveries'],
          @Html.Raw(rows6)]);

        var options = {
            region: 'ZA',
            displayMode: 'auto',
            //colorAxis: { colors: ['#cccccc', '#C01E24'] },
            resolution: 'provinces',
            height: '390'

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
</script>
```

This is how it displays:

[image]

How do I get to only display South Africa like this, without the ocean and surrounding countries (For Example)

[image]

If anyone needs additional information, please let me know and I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible approach(requires that the datatable contains data for all provinces in the particular country and no data for other countries):

define the `datalessRegionColor`-option(it doesn't matter which color, but it should be unique in the map, so take some unusual color).

The API will use this color to set the fill-color-attributes for unused regions. What's the purpose of this color for you? when you know an attribute of an element, you be able to define a selector for this element.

The simple CSS-solution would be:

```
path[fill='#123456']{display:none !important;}
```

### Demo:

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Province', 'Successful Deliveries'],
    ['ZA-EC', null],
    ['ZA-FS', null],
    ['ZA-GT', 500],
    ['ZA-NL', null],
    ['ZA-LP', null],
    ['ZA-MP', null],
    ['ZA-NC', null],
    ['ZA-NW', null],
    ['ZA-WC', 100]
  ]);

  var options = {
    datalessRegionColor: '#123456',
    region: 'ZA',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    defaultColor: '#ffffff',
    keepAspectRatio: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#regions_div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#regions_div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
path[fill='#123456'] {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
<div id="regions_div" "></div>
```

### Demo related to the comments:

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Province', 'Successful Deliveries'],
    ['ZA-EC', null],
    ['ZA-FS', null],
    ['ZA-GT', 500],
    ['ZA-NL', null],
    ['ZA-LP', null],
    ['ZA-MP', null],
    ['ZA-NC', null],
    ['ZA-NW', null],
    ['ZA-WC', 100]
  ]);

  var options = {
    datalessRegionColor: '#123456',
    region: 'ZA',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    defaultColor: '#ffffff',
    keepAspectRatio: true,
    tooltip:{trigger:'selection'},
    width:1000,height:600
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
#regions_div{
  position:relative;
  width:310px;
  height:270px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid silver;
}
#regions_div svg{
  position:absolute;
  left:-300px;
  top:-20px;
}
path[fill='#123456'] {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
<div id="regions_div" "></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to make the map bigger?

Comment: you may control the size of the map via width/height. But I guess what you mean is the  space around the country...there is no API-method to set the displayed area(except the country-code). But you may use a little bit CSS to clip the map to the desired area(but then you will not see a legend and the hover-tooltips). I've added a demo above